# How do i add web service to my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, proxy, web

Everybody i need some help about web services

I want to add web service to my project but i got an error .

Web service adress is https://interaktifkargo.ptt.gov.tr/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay

When i want to add vs2010 add web service

Error is

> ```
> 'https://interaktifkargo.ptt.gov.tr/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay'
> ```
>
> accor while loading .connection close.The process of sending an
>   unexpected error has occurred.
>       Unexpected end of file, or 0 bytes were received transport stream.
>       Metadata contains a reference çözümlemeyen: 'https://interaktifkargo.ptt.gov.tr/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay'.
>       https://interaktifkargo.ptt.gov.tr/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay an error occurred during the HTTP request. This is because the HTTPS
>   server certificate is not configured properly may be the case with
>   HTTP.SYS. At the same time, a security binding mismatch between the
>   client and the server may have originated due.
>       The underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred while sending process.
>       Unexpected end of file, or 0 bytes were received transport stream.
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Any one can help to me ?

Comment: java code http://www.speedyshare.com/file/Fbxpc/JAVA-KOD-1.txt for this web service but i dont know java exactly

Comment: You don't have to know Java to use the webservice, you can do it in c# once you generate a proxy class for the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is from the security certificate of the website. 
You can download the WSDL file, conventionally by appending ?wsdl to the end of the url, save to your local system and then generate the proxy from the visual studio command line. 
Depending on your version of VS, you will use wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe from the command line to generate a proxy from a wsdl file on your local system.

Comment: <service name="topluTakipDetay">
<port name="GonderiTakipPort" binding="tns:GonderiTakipBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8888/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay"/>
</port>
</service>   and of the wsdl code soap address location looking localhost do we have any problem for this adrees ? i can use web service https://interaktifkargo.ptt.gov.tr/topluTakipDetay/topluTakipDetay?operation=gonderiSorgula from this link but i want to add my application

Comment: how can i generate the proxy ?i can send java code for this service but i dont know java exactly ?

Comment: @ÖmerOruç, save the xml to your disk and add a service reference using an url like `file://c:/temp/ptt.xml`

Comment: @ÖmerOruç It's not a problem that the location is localhost right now. You can always set the Url on the instance of the proxy class you generate. If the wsdl if well formed, you'll have a Url property on the proxy instance and you can set it back to the correct url.